# My code does not place the values every row, instead skips rows based on source sheet layout

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that searches through Sheet("Sub Tasks") and if the number in column A is a decimal, it then makes cells in Sheet("PBS") Column D = to the offset of the decimal cell found in column A. However, I would like the code to work by making row 2,3,4,5,6, and so on (+1) in sheet PBS display the info from Sub tasks.

But at the moment, the info is displayed in the same layout as it is in Sheet("Sub Tasks"). What am i missing from the code.

```````````````````````````
Dim Lastrow3 As Long, r As Long, n As Long, cell As Range, ws As Worksheet, Lastrow1 As Long
Lastrow3 = Sheets("Sub Tasks").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow1 = Sheets("PBS ").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

n = 2
With Worksheets("Sub Tasks")
        For Each cell In Sheets("Sub Tasks").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow3)
            If IsNumeric(cell.value) Then
                If cell.value = Int(cell.value) Then
                   Worksheets("PBS ").Cells(n, "C").value = cell.value
                   Worksheets("PBS ").Cells(n, "D").value = cell.Offset(0, 1).value
                   Worksheets("PBS ").Cells(n, "B").value = cell.Offset(0, 8).value
                   Worksheets("PBS ").Cells(n, "A").value = cell.Offset(0, 7).value
                   Worksheets("PBS ").Cells(n, "H").value = cell.Offset(0, 23).value
                   Worksheets("PBS ").Cells(n, "E").value = cell.Offset(0, 3).value
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        n = n + 1
    Next cell
End With
``````````````````````````
```````````````````````````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `n = n + 1` to another place.

```
    n = 2
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow3)
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            If cell.Value = Int(cell.Value) Then
               Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(n, "C").Value = cell.Value
               Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(n, "D").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
               Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(n, "B").Value = cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
               Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(n, "A").Value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
               Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(n, "H").Value = cell.Offset(0, 23).Value
               Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(n, "E").Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
               n = n + 1
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```